# Cycles volumetrics: artifacts on edges

Tags: cycles-render-engine, volumetrics

I'm creating cloud in Blender/Cycles. While following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=90wsacQJJoo) tutorial I came across artifacts:[image]. The problem is marked on render (the biggest visible artifact) and seems to appear in areas where faces overlaps in particular way, this places are significantly darker. If I would smooth the geometry, they will go away, but the thing is that I want to keep such fluffy shapes. Does someone know how can it be fixed without changing topology?

Comment: I think you will get better results using the new [Point Density](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/textures/types/volume/point_density.html) feature. Clouds are not solid meshes in real life, so trying to mimic them using meshes is a hacky workaround at best. I'm not saying it can't be done - just that you will have more headaches if doing it with meshes.

Comment: Those are likely caused by intersecting geometry. Try turning down the amount of displacement if you can, or perhaps a remesh modifier. Also see http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/16188/599